# Disable Zsh history completely

Tags: zsh

I would like to disable Zsh history (arrow up) and zle history search (namely esc+p) completely. How can I achieve this?

My current `.zshrc`:

```
unsetopt hist_append
unsetopt hist_expand
HISTFILE=
HISTSIZE=SAVEHIST=0
```

Currently I have history buffer of one, but I'd like to have history of zero.

21-10-2016 Update:

I've added

```
bindkey -r "^[p"
bindkey -r "^Xr"
bindkey -r "^Xs"
bindkey -r "^[[A"
bindkey -r "^[[B"
bindkey -r "^[n"
```

to get rid of history features that I use (esc+p is deeply hardwired to my backbone - so difficult to unlearn).

Comment: Unrelated, but I'm pretty sure this construct      HISTSIZE=SAVEHIST=0      does not work.

Comment: I think it does, however HISTSIZE cannot be set to zero for some reason.
`% HISTSIZE=SAVEHIST=4`
`% echo $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST`
`4 4`
`% HISTSIZE=0`
`% echo $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST`
`1 4`
`% HISTSIZE=SAVEHIST=0`
`% echo $HISTSIZE $SAVEHIST`
`1 0`

Comment: Hm.  Today I learned.

Comment: Yeah me too! :)

Comment: I think chained assignment like this only works for parameters using an integer representation internally (i.e., `typeset -i`).

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is:
`% HISTSIZE=0`
`% typeset -i|grep HISTSIZE`
`HISTSIZE=1`

Comment: His point is that for a normal shell variable, `A=B=5` puts the value `B=5` into the variable `A`.  But if you mark the variable as specifically "integers only", than `A=B=5` will put the value `5` into both variables `A` and `B`.  This trick doesn't work for all variables, only for variables that are specifically "integer only".  It's not an answer to your original question.  It's continuing the discussion on chained variable assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in the zsh man page that completely disables history.  Even setting `HISTSIZE=0` seems to reset the value of `HISTSIZE` to 1.

You'll probably have better luck changing the key bindings with `bindkey` so that history features never occur.  For example, `bindkey -r "^[[A"` for my up-arrow key (note that I actually typed a caret and two brackets, not an escape key).

Answer (score 6):

I use following entries in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias disablehistory="function zshaddhistory() {  return 1 }"
```

If function [zshaddhistory](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html) is defined, it can control whether history line will be saved.

Therefore, alias `disablehistory` will just define function that always returns 1 (don't save).

```
alias disablehistory="function zshaddhistory() {  return 1 }"
```

```
alias enablehistory="unset -f zshaddhistory"
```

`enablehistory` just unsets function set by previous alias.

If you want to disable history completely, permanently define `zshaddhistory` in your `.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your ZSH setup to run a postexec function that empties/deletes your .zhistory file. It's a hacky workaround but should probably work.

Comment: Currently HISTFILE="" I've also tried HISTFILE="/dev/null" with no luck. No hacks around here!